# How to get 2nd line of text response in fetch in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

[image]

Here I want to display only 2nd line in `toast` message, so how can I get the 2nd line. I didn't found any solution so please help me.

Here is my API call code:

```
fetch(`${API_URL}api/${id}`, {
      method: 'get',  
    })
      .then((response) => {
        responseValue = response.status; // this is variable

        return response.text();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (responseValue === 500) {
          console.log('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^');
          console.log(result);
        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

hear are error

```
Exception at /api/5fbf49d35d7473bf278149bc
Folio data not found

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://example.com/api/barcode/bills/5fbf49d35d7473bf278149bc
Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.6.9
   
Exception Type: Exception at /api/
Exception Value: Folio data not found
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data
```

Comment: You need to provide some code snippets how you are making this API call

Comment: ok i will update my question

Comment: ok question updated

Comment: @miteshkalal Can you provide us result text also?

Comment: ya sure i update in question

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about something as basic as splitting a given text by newlines (which you should be able to easily research on your own.)

Comment: @CBroe I try to much with javascript spilt() but can't achieve the desired output

Comment: so what is the exact expected result here?

Comment: i want "Folio data not found" this line

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried (in form of a _proper_ [mre], meaning include the fetch response as static data if necessary), instead of just _saying_ that you tried stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `split` as following.

```js
console.log(error.split('\n')[1]);
```